# What was the Sully wing in the Louvre originally?

Tags: france, paris

I'm trying to find an exact idea of what the state of the Louvre was in 1677 during the reign of Louis XIV and the beginning of the Poisons Affair, particularly the Sully wing. Would it have still been under construction or would construction of that wing been finished by that time? Would any artists be painting there? Could normal citizens enter?